# Tweet embed in blockquote broken

Tags: twitter, jekyll

I am running a jekyll site on github.io

When I embed a tweet, the blockquote doesn't close and takes over the rest of the text. The problem disappears if I take out the link and any other text beetween

and

So, this doesnt work

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">I liked the film Idiocracy by Mike Judge, but I wish they didn’t turn it into a multi-season reality show</p>&mdash; Kyle Wild (@dorkitude) <a href="https://twitter.com/dorkitude/status/1029846666558492673?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">August 15, 2018</a></blockquote>
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

but when i have a blockquote like this it does (obviously not for embedding a tweet)

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">I liked the film Idiocracy by Mike Judge, but I wish they didn’t turn it into a multi-season reality show</p></blockquote>
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

thanks!

Comment: Solved. I just put the paragraph closure at the end, leaving href and everyrthing inside.